# Accessing Data on Linked List? Java

Tags: java, list, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have a linked list with a String and a Int. How can I access the int?
For example, the user selects Football and Basketball (String = "Football" with Int as 11. And "Basketball" with Int 5).
If I call Football and Basketball the display should show 16.

Here is my code:

```
public StringNode_1(String s, Integer i, StringNode_1 sn) {
  Sport= s;
  Amount= i;
  next = sn;
```

For the Main program:

```
public void addNode(String s, int i){
  StringNode_1 curnode;
  curnode = head;
  while(curnode.next != null) {
    curnode = curnode.next;

  }
  curnode.next = new StringNode_1(s,i,null);
}
```

And this:

```
SLinkedList_1 thelist = new SLinkedList_1();
thelist.addFirst("Cricket", 5);
thelist.addNode("Football", 11);
thelist.addNode("Basketball", 5);
printList(thelist);
```

Comment: Can you share some code ?

Comment: For the Node i Have :
public StringNode_1(String s, Integer i, StringNode_1 sn) {
        
      
      Sport= s;
      Amount= i;
      next = sn;


For the Main program: 

public  void addNode(String s, int i){
        
        StringNode_1 curnode;
        
        curnode = head;
        
        while(curnode.next != null) {
            
            curnode = curnode.next;
       
       //  System.out.println(curnode.Station + " " + curnode.Distance);
                 
         
        }
             
        curnode.next = new StringNode_1(s,i,null);
        
            }

Comment: And this


                  SLinkedList_1 thelist = new SLinkedList_1();
        
        
                thelist.addFirst("London", 5);            
                    
          thelist.addNode("Football", 11);
          thelist.addNode("Basketball", 5);
          
                    
                   
          printList(thelist);

Comment: I have added your code in your original question, but I think it's not a relevant part for your question.